# how to use ContainsKey with Linq and manage the case if key not found

Tags: c#, linq

How do you convert this code into Linq lambda expression?

```
var list = new List<string[]>();
foreach (var @char in _word)
{
     if (mapping.ContainsKey(@char.ToString()))   // I tried with TryGetValue but my brain has thrown a stackoverflow.
          list.Add(mapping[@char.ToString()]);
     else
           list.Add(mapping["?"]);
}
```

If there were no else part in my previous code, the linq expression would be like the following code but I don't know how **also** to manage the case where key is not found.

```
var list = _word.ToCharArray()
                .Where(mot => mapping.ContainsKey(mot.ToString()))
                .Select(mot => mapping[mot.ToString()]);
```

The solution must preserve the order please.

Comment: What is type of object is mapping?

Comment: If the key in your "mapping" dictionary is always a single character, you could improve performance by making the key type actually be `char` instead of `string`. That way you can cut out all the calls to convert characters into strings over and over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var list = _word.Select(mot => mapping.ContainsKey(mot.ToString()) ? mapping[mot.ToString()] : mapping["?"]);
```

Comment: `ToCharArray` is redundant because `String` is already `IEnumerable<char>`.